# convert 6 digit int into to yyyymm in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I made a file that had three date columns:

```
pd.DataFrame({'yyyymm':[199501],'yyyy':[1995],'mm':[1],'Address':['AL1'],'Number':[12]})
    yyyymm  yyyy    mm  Address Number
0   199501  1995    1   AL1     12
```

and saved it as a file:

```
df.to_csv('complete.csv')
```

I read in the file with:

```
df=pd.read_csv('complete.csv')
```

and my 3 date columns are converted to int's, and not dates.

I tried to convert them back to dates with:

```
df['yyyymm']=df['yyyymm'].astype(str).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
df['yyyy']=df['yyyy'].dt.strftime('%Y')
df['mm']=df['mm'].dt.dtrftime('%m')
```

with the error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Very odd, as the command I used to make the datetime column was:

```
df['yyyymm']=df['col2'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

Am I missing something? HOw can I convert the 6 digit column back to yyyymm datetime, the 4 digit column to yyyy datetime, and the mm digit column back to datetime?

Comment: `'yyymm'` is not a valid datetime https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: `df['yyyymm']` is an *integer*, not a datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns `yyyymm` and `yyyy` and `mm` are *integers*. By using `.astype(str)`, you convert these to strings. But a string has no `.dt`.

You can use [**`pd.to_datetime(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert these to a datetime object:

```
df['yyyymm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yyyymm'].astype(str), format='%Y%m')
```

Indeed, this gives us:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['yyyymm'].astype(str), format='%Y%m')
0   1995-01-01
Name: yyyymm, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The same can be done for the `yyyy` and `mm` columns:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['yyyy'].astype(str), format='%Y')
0   1995-01-01
Name: yyyy, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['mm'].astype(str), format='%m')
0   1900-01-01
Name: mm, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: thanks. I ended up creating a new column that converted it to yyyy-mm-dd, and then extract formats I wanted from original question, but you gave me the correct guidance